# Python Caesar Cipher Decoder

Tags: python, decoding, encryption

In my lesson I was tasked with creating a Caesar Cipher decoder that takes a string of input and finds the best possible string using a letter frequencies. If not sure how much sense that made but let post the question:

*Write a program which does the following. First, it should read one line of input, which is the encoded message, and will consist of capital letters and spaces. Your program must try decoding the message with all 26 possible values of the shift S; out of these 26 possible original messages, print the one which has the highest goodness.
For your convenience, we will pre-define the variable letterGoodness for you, a list of length 26 which equals the values in the frequency table above*

[image: Letter Frequencies]

I have this code so far:

```
x = input()
NUM_LETTERS = 26 #Can't import modules I'm using a web based grader/compiler
def SpyCoder(S, N):
    y = ""
    for i in S:
        x = ord(i)
        x += N
        if x > ord('Z'):
            x -= NUM_LETTERS
        elif x < ord('A'):
            x += NUM_LETTERS
        y += chr(x)
    return y  

def GoodnessFinder(S):
    y = 0
    for i in S:
        if x != 32:
            x = ord(i)
            x -= ord('A')
            y += letterGoodness[x]
    return y 

def GoodnessComparer(S):
    goodnesstocompare = GoodnessFinder(S)
    goodness = 0
    v = ''
    for i in range(0, 26):
        v = SpyCoder(S, i)
        goodness = GoodnessFinder(v)
        if goodness > goodnesstocompare:
            goodnesstocompare = goodness
    return v

y = x.split()
z = ''
for i in range(0, len(y)):
    if i == len(y) - 1:
        z += GoodnessComparer(y[i])
print(z)
```

EDIT: Made changes suggested by Cristian Ciupitu
Please ignore indentation errors, they probably arose when I copied my code over.

The program works like this:

- Take the input and split it into a list
- For every list value I feed it to a goodness finder.
- It takes the goodness of the string and compares everything else against and when    there's a higher goodness it makes the higher one the goodness to compare.
- It then shifts that string of text by i amount to see if the goodness is higher or lower

I'm not quite sure where the problem is, the first test: LQKP OG CV GKIJV DA VJG BQQ
Prints the correct message: JOIN ME AT AT BY THE ZOO

However the next test: UIJT JT B TBNQMF MJOF PG UFYU GPS EFDSZQUJOH
Gives the a junk string of: SGHR HR Z RZLOKD KHMD NE SDWS ENQ CDBQXOSHMF
When it's supposed to be: THIS IS A SAMPLE LINE OF TEXT FOR DECRYPTING

I know I have to:
Try every shift value
Get the 'goodness' of the word
Return the string with the highest goodness.

I hope my explanation made sense as I am quite confused at the moment.

Comment: If you add 1 to every character in the junk string 'SGHR HR Z RZLOKD ...' you get 'THIS IS A SAMPLE ...', so it's very nearly right.

Comment: You should try replacing some of the magical numbers with meaningful constants, e.g. 65 with `ord('A')`, 26 with `NUM_LETTERS`. By the way in `GoodnessComparer` you have `range(0, 25)` instead of `(0, 26)`; is that a typo or not?  And another thing: in `GoodnessFinder` you don't need to do `ord(i)` every time, only when `i` is a space (`' '`).

Comment: [input()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) is equivalent with `eval(raw_input())` which doesn't make sense, so replace it with a plain `raw_input()` call.

Comment: @Cristian Ciupitu: That should be Python 3 code.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Okay I did the first two, I actually had no idea NUM_LETTERS existed till now. GoodnessComparer gives a junk string for the first value if the range is 0, 26.

Comment: @Thegluestickman: NUM_LETTERS was just an example. You still need to declare it or if you wish to, you can import the `string` module and use `len(string.ascii_uppercase)`.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Whoops, I added that in thinking it was a constant, turns out it was just never called :P I'm also still not quite sure what you mean about ord(i) in goodness finder. Why am I checking only when i is a space? How would I know what letter goodness I was looking for?

Comment: Another unrelated thing: in `SpyCoder` you should iterate directly over `S` the same way you do it in `GoodnessFinder`; there's no need for an index. Also, what happens if the current character is not a (uppercase) letter?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu If I were making this program for a user I would definitely add lowercase but for this assignment any test will always be uppercase.

Comment: What about spaces? `S` can contain spaces or tabs or punctuation marks etc., right?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Only spaces are part of the grading

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11850/discussion-between-cristian-ciupitu-and-thegluestickman)

Comment: "Please ignore indentation errors" in Python code, for real?

Comment: @Kay Cristian was nice enough to indent for me, but what I meant by that is that indentation isn't the source of error.

Comment: Since Stack Overflow allows you to post an answer to your own question and this is a homework, you should post your final version of the decoder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My final solution that works, thanks to the wonderful Cristian Ciupitu.

```
x = input()
NUM_LETTERS = 26 #Can't import modules I'm using a web based grader/compiler
def SpyCoder(S, N):
   y = ""
   for i in S:
      if(i.isupper()):
         x = ord(i)
         x += N
         if x > ord('Z'):
            x -= NUM_LETTERS
         elif x < ord('A'):
            x += NUM_LETTERS
         y += chr(x)
      else:
         y += " "
   return y

def GoodnessFinder(S):
   y = 0
   for i in S:
      if i.isupper():
         x = ord(i)
         x -= ord('A')
         y += letterGoodness[x]
      else:
         y += 1
   return y

def GoodnessComparer(S):
   goodnesstocompare = GoodnessFinder(S)
   goodness = 0
   v = ''
   best_v = S
   for i in range(0, 26):
     v = SpyCoder(S, i)
     goodness = GoodnessFinder(v)
     if goodness > goodnesstocompare:
         best_v = v
         goodnesstocompare = goodness
   return best_v


print(GoodnessComparer(x))
```

Thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 3):

Here is my implementation which works fine.

You should print the goodness of each possible message and see why your program output it.

```
letterGoodness = dict(zip(string.ascii_uppercase,
                        [.0817,.0149,.0278,.0425,.1270,.0223,.0202,
                         .0609,.0697,.0015,.0077,.0402,.0241,.0675,
                         .0751,.0193,.0009,.0599,.0633,.0906,.0276,
                         .0098,.0236,.0015,.0197,.0007]))

trans_tables = [ str.maketrans(string.ascii_uppercase,
                 string.ascii_uppercase[i:]+string.ascii_uppercase[:i])
                 for i in range(26)]

def goodness(msg):
    return sum(letterGoodness.get(char, 0) for char in msg)

def all_shifts(msg):
    msg = msg.upper()
    for trans_table in trans_tables:
        txt = msg.translate(trans_table)
        yield goodness(txt), txt

print(max(all_shifts(input())))
```

Comment: You've noticed the *homework* tag, right? Your answer is way too good.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: So he can't just submit it but learning first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same tutorial and used a slightly different method. This avoided creating and calling functions:

```
inp = input()     #to hold code text
code = list(inp)  #store code as a list
soln = []         #store the 'Goodness' for each of 26 possible answers
y=0               #variable to hold total goodness during calculations
clear = []        #will hold decoded text
pos=0             #position marker for a list

#for every possible value of shift
#note range as 0 to 25 are valid shifts and shift 26 = shift 0

for shift in range(0,26):
   for i in code:                  #loop through each letter in code
      if i == " ":                 #spaces have no score so omit them
         continue
      else:                        #if it's a letter
         x = ord(i)-shift          #apply the test shift
         if x < 65:                #prevent shifting outside A-Z range
            x = x + 26             
         x = x - 64                #turn ord into character position in A-Z with A=1
         x = letterGoodness[x-1]   #turn this into the Goodness score
         y = y + x                 #add this to a running total
   soln.insert(shift-1,y)          #AFTER decoding all letters in code, add total(y) to list of scores
   y = 0                           #reset y before next test value

bestSoln=max(soln)                 #find highest possible score

for i in range(0,26):              #check the list of solutions for this score
   if soln[i]==bestSoln:           #the position in this list is the shift we need
       bestShift = i+1             #+1 as the first solution is 0

for i in code:                     #now decode the original text using our best solution
   if i == " ":                    #spaces are not encoded so just add these to the string
      clear.insert(pos," ")        #pos used to track next position for final string
      pos = pos + 1
      continue
   else:
      x = ord(i)-bestShift         #same operation as before
      if x < 65:
         x = x + 26
   z = chr(x)
   clear.insert(pos,z)             #add the decoded letter to the clear text
   pos = pos + 1
print("".join(clear))              #join the list of clear text into one string and print it
```

Note that many parts of this code could (and should) be compressed, for example

```
x = x - 64
x = letterGoodness[x-1]
y = y + x
```

They are left expanded to 'show my working' for a tutorial exercise.

Answer (score 0):

```
letterGoodness = {'A': 8.17, 'B': 1.49, 'C': 2.78, 'D': 4.25, 'E': 12.70,
                  'F': 2.23, 'G': 2.02, 'H': 6.09, 'I': 6.97, 'J': 0.05, 
                  'K': 0.77, 'L': 4.02, 'M': 2.41, 'N': 6.75, 'O': 7.51, 
                  'P': 1.93, 'Q': 0.09, 'R': 5.99, 'S': 6.33, 'T': 9.06, 
                  'U': 2.76, 'V': 0.98, 'W': 2.36, 'X': 0.15, 'Y': 1.97, 
                  'Z': 0.07} 
                  
# em - input message
em = str(input()) 
em = em.upper()

# dm - guess message
dm = '' 
dmList = []
goodnessList = []
shift = 1

for g in range(25):
   goodness = 0
   dm = ''
   for i in em:
       newL = chr(ord(i) - shift)
       if i == ' ':
            dm += i

       elif ord(newL) < 65:
               A = ord(newL) + 90
               newL = chr(A - 64)
               dm += newL

       else:
            dm += newL

   for h in dm:
      if h != ' ':
         goodness += letterGoodness[h]
   goodnessList.append(goodness)
         
   shift += 1
   dmList.append(dm)  

highestG = max(goodnessList)
dmind = goodnessList.index(highestG)
print(dmList[dmind])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def start():
   message = input()                                        ## collect user input
   maxGoodness = 0                                          ## stablish a benchmark
   maxGoodnessMessage = message                             ## use current message as baseline
   for i in range(0,26):                                    ## for each range of 1-26 the range of the alphabet and goodness
      currentMessage = decodeMesssage(message, i)           ## decode the message for the current i
      currentGoodness = calculateGoodness(currentMessage)   ##  calculate the goodness for decoded message
      if currentGoodness > maxGoodness:                     ## compare goodness to last iteration, if greater
         maxGoodness = currentGoodness                      ## update maxGoodness
         maxGoodnessMessage = currentMessage                ## store decipher message with current max goodness
         
   print(maxGoodnessMessage)

def decodeMesssage(message, S):                             ## decode message
   newMessage = ''                                          ## start with an empty message 
   for letter in message:                                   ## for each letter in the message 
      if ord(letter) == 32:                                 ## if we get an empty character just add it to the message and continue to next iteration
        newMessage = newMessage + letter
        continue
      currentAscii = ord(letter) + S                        ## calculate the value of the current letter and add the S= value
      if currentAscii > 90:                                 ## if the value of current letter + S is 90 meaning letter Z
         currentAscii = currentAscii-26                     ## find next letter starting from A
      newMessage += str(chr(currentAscii))                  ## transform back to a letter and add to message
   return newMessage 
 
def calculateGoodness(message): 
   total = 0
   for char in message:                                     ## for each character in the message
      if char == ' ':                                       ## ignore empty characters
         continue
      i = ord(char)
      total += letterGoodness[i-65]                        ## calculate the  value of the character and add it to total
   return total
      
   
   
start()
```